# rotating list item

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have created a list item which rotates but I would like to introduce two buttons to control the list. The first button should basically let the list-item move upwards and the second bottom should do the reverse, that is let the list-items slide down.

This is the code i am using to rotate the list is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S8Mfa/)

Thanks

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: so you want toselect a list-item to be moved as well?

Comment: in essence, my question is how do i include two buttons in the code..The first button, when clicked should allow the list scroll down, and the second button, when clicked should allow the list scroll up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split give the buttons two classes `.up` and `.down` and attach the events

**[working version on fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ebDhF/)** or [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ebDhF/1/)

```
$(".up").click(function(){
    $("ul li:first").slideUp('slow', function () {
         $("ul li:last").after($(this));
    }).slideDown('slow');
});

$(".down").click(function(){
    $("ul li:last").slideUp('slow', function () {
         $("ul li:first").before($(this));
    }).slideDown('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to control the direction of the list's rotation. 
If so, try this:

```
var direction = 'down';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var swap = function () {
            if (direction == 'down') {
                $("ul li:last").slideUp('slow', function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                    $("ul").prepend($(this));
                    $(this).slideDown('slow', function () {
                        swap();
                    });
                });
            }
            else {
                $("ul li:first").slideDown('slow', function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                    $("ul").append($(this));
                    $(this).slideUp('slow', function () {
                        swap();
                    });
                });
            }
        }
        swap();
    });
```

Then all your buttons need to do is change the value of "direction", e.g.

```
onclick="direction = 'up';"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i am yet to try the above code but it does look close to what i am seeking. :)